# Prime number generator returns none at the end when inside a function sometimes

Tags: python-3.x

I made this prime number generator in python:

```
for x in range(a , b):
    y = 2
    while 1 == 1:
        if x % y == 0:
            if x == y:
                print(x)
                break
            else:
                break
        y += 1
```

and it returns all prime numbers up to b as long as a > 2 and b > 3

for example, when a = 2 and b = 11 i get this

```
2
3
5
7
```

but when I nest it inside a function like this and print it:

```
def f(b,a=2):
    for x in range(a , b):
        y = 2
        while 1 == 1:
            if x % y == 0:
                if x == y:
                    print(x)
                    break
                else:
                    break
            y += 1
print(f(11))
```

I get this:

```
2
3
5
7
None?
```

Why is it printing a none while inside a function and not without?  And how would I fix this?

Comment: Why do you say `while 1 == 1:` instead of `while True:`?

Comment: It's because you're printing the return value of a function that returns None. If there is no executed return statement in a function, Python will add an implicit `return None`. If you change `print(f(n))` to simply `f(n)`, it should no longer print `None`